# How can I span multiple strings in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I tried this code to create a TextView with the string "abcde"  where 'b' and 'd' have spanning:

```
private void testStringSpanning(TextView tv)
{
    // blue
    ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan( Color.BLUE );

    SpannableString  a = new SpannableString( "a" );
    SpannableString  b = new SpannableString( "b" );    
    b.setSpan( fcs, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
    SpannableString  c = new SpannableString( "c" );
    SpannableString  d = new SpannableString( "d" );    
    d.setSpan( fcs, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
    SpannableString  e = new SpannableString( "e" );

    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append(a);
    builder.append(b);
    builder.append(c);
    builder.append(d);
    builder.append(e);

    tv.setText( builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

The result is not as I want. a, c and e should be plain white and b d should be blue.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: result string with 'a' in plain white and 'bdce' in blue]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan( Color.BLUE );

//your strings in case you have most than one
String str1 = new String("a");
String str2 = new String("b");
String str3 = new String("c");
String str4 = new String("d");

//or a single one str = new String ("abcd")

//set all to on a TV
TextView string =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvString);
string.setText( str1 + str2 + str3 + str4, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE );

//convert all string y a single SpannableString
SpannableString s = (SpannableString)string.getText();

//This variables hepl you counting large strings
int str1_lenght = str1.length();
int str2_lenght = srt2.length();
int str3_lenght = srt3.length();
int str4_lenght = srt4.length();

//setting color on an specific string
s.setSpan(fcs, str1_lenght, str1_lenght + str2_lenght, 0);
s.setSpan(fcs, str1_lenght + str2_lenght + str3_lenght, str1_lenght + str2_lenght + str3_lenght + str4_lenght, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you setSpan to the letters C and E, does it look correct at that point?  I have a feeling that the setSpan on letter B is overwriting the 'default' on the remaining characters.  That's my shot in the dark.

Comment: Setting span to C and E extends the blue area to C D and E.